# Best data type to store list of strings?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, types, ienumerable

In .NET which data type do you use to store list of strings ?

Currently I'm using `List(Of String)` because it's easier than `Array` to manage and add/remove stuff. I'm trying to understand what are the other options, when they become handy and when I should avoid `List(Of String)` usage.

Do you use another type? Why and When?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List(Of String)` is a perfectly good way of storing a list of strings. If you need to add/remove elements from in the middle, you might want to consider using a `LinkedList(Of String)` but for most situations `List` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Almost always [`List<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) or [`Dictionary<TKey, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

List for when you need an index-based list, and Dictionary when you want random access to a string value given a specified key.

However, try to stick to [`IList<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) and [`IDictionary<TKey, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) where possible, of course.

Answer (score 2):

System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection is also an option, but personally I prefer List(Of String).

Answer (score 2):

I think the name says it all really: in most circumstances *`List(Of String)`* is the best way to store a *list of strings*.